Improving Location Accuracy in .NET MAUI User Tracking Application
I'm developing a user tracking application using .NET MAUI, but I'm encountering significant issues with location accuracy. The captured latitude and longitude often show incorrect positions, even when the user is stationary. I'm looking for ways to improve the accuracy and reliability of location data. Here are the details:
Current Setup:
Using Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors to capture location data.
Requesting GeolocationAccuracy.Best for location updates. Handling necessary permissions in both Android.
Problems Encountered:
Significant deviation in latitude and longitude values.
Incorrect location data even when the user hasn't moved.
Sporadic jumps in location points resulting in inaccurate tracking.
Latitude and Longitude miss accuracy screenshot:

How can I improve the accuracy of location data in my .NET MAUI application? Are there any best practices or techniques to minimize incorrect location readings and achieve more reliable tracking? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Code:
Below logic for I am using to fetch location details
    private async Task<Location> GetLocationDetails()
    {
        Location location = null;
        try
        {
            _isCheckingLocation = true;
    
            GeolocationRequest request = new(GeolocationAccuracy.Best,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            request.RequestFullAccuracy = true;
    
            _cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    
            location = await Geolocation.Default.GetLocationAsync(request);
    
            if (location == null)
            {
                _errorLogAPI.Log($"Unable to Get Accurate Location Details. (Getting Last Known Location)", "GetLocationDetails", LogType.Crit);
                location = await Geolocation.Default.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (FeatureNotSupportedException ex)
        {
            _errorLogAPI.Log($"Location Service is Not Supported", "GetLocationDetails", LogType.Crit, ex);
            throw;
        }
        catch (FeatureNotEnabledException ex)
        {
            _errorLogAPI.Log($"Location Service is Not Enabled", "GetLocationDetails", LogType.Crit, ex);
            throw;
        }
        catch (PermissionException ex)
        {
            _errorLogAPI.Log($"Location Permission is Not Given", "GetLocationDetails", LogType.Crit, ex);
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _errorLogAPI.Log($"Unable to Get Location", "GetLocationDetails", LogType.Crit, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            _isCheckingLocation = false;
        }
        return location;
    }


Did you use the GetCachedLocation() method in your project? While checking for the last known location of the device may be quicker, it can be inaccurate.

@GuangyuBai-MSFT - Thanks for your response.
I have added my location fetch logic. can you look into above forum

First, you can try to use the code in the document of Geolocation. you can use the GeolocationAccuracy.Mediumand TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) to achieve the data slowly, this would make the line in the chart smooth.
Second, this value RequestFullAccuracy is only used on iOS 14+. Using this functionality requires the NSLocationTemporaryUsageDescriptionDictionary key to be present in the info.plist file. You can add the #if ios for this value.
Last, if you are using the android platform, make sure the add the assembly-based permission.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />


now compare to previous too much of miss accurate data
Lat Lon: 11.407689999999999,78.19690666666666
Order By: 15
Timestamp: 2024-07-22T14:36:57+05:30
Accuracy: 18.600000381469727 meters
Vertical Accuracy: 100.0999984741211 meters
Reduced Accuracy: false
Speed: 7.948855400085449 m/s
Course: 179.08999633789062 degrees

GeolocationAccuracy.Best is the most accurate mode for GeolocationRequest request.

I'm developing a similar app and have added both a valid location method and a smoothing method. Maybe you'd want something like that?
Last valid location method:
  private const double MAX_ACCURACY = 30.0; // meters
private const double MAX_SPEED = 8.0; // 8 m/s (about 28.8 km/h)
private const double MIN_DISTANCE = 0.5; // meters
private const int MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 500; // milliseconds
private MauiLocation lastAcceptedLocation;

private bool IsValidLocation(MauiLocation newLocation, MauiLocation previousLocation)
{
    if (previousLocation == null || lastAcceptedLocation == null)
    {
        lastAcceptedLocation = newLocation;
        Console.WriteLine("First location, automatically valid");
        Logger.LogInfo("First location, automatically valid");
        return true;
    }

    var timeSinceLastUpdate = (newLocation.Timestamp - previousLocation.Timestamp).TotalMilliseconds;
    var distanceFromPrevious = CalculateDistanceBetweenPoints(
        new Coordinate { Latitude = previousLocation.Latitude, Longitude = previousLocation.Longitude },
        new Coordinate { Latitude = newLocation.Latitude, Longitude = newLocation.Longitude }
    ) * 1000; // Convert km to meters
    var distanceFromLastAccepted = CalculateDistanceBetweenPoints(
        new Coordinate { Latitude = lastAcceptedLocation.Latitude, Longitude = lastAcceptedLocation.Longitude },
        new Coordinate { Latitude = newLocation.Latitude, Longitude = newLocation.Longitude }
    ) * 1000; // Convert km to meters
    var timeSinceLastAccepted = (newLocation.Timestamp - lastAcceptedLocation.Timestamp).TotalSeconds;
    var speed = timeSinceLastAccepted > 0 ? distanceFromLastAccepted / timeSinceLastAccepted : 0;


    var logMessage = $"Time since last update: {timeSinceLastUpdate}ms, Distance from previous: {distanceFromPrevious:F2}m, Distance from last accepted: {distanceFromLastAccepted:F2}m, Time since last accepted: {timeSinceLastAccepted:F2}s, Speed: {speed * 3.6:F2} km/h";
    Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
    Logger.LogInfo(logMessage);

    if (newLocation.Accuracy > MAX_ACCURACY)
    {
        var rejectMessage = $"Rejected point due to low accuracy: {newLocation.Accuracy}m";
        Console.WriteLine(rejectMessage);
        Logger.LogInfo(rejectMessage);
        return false;
    }

    if (distanceFromPrevious < MIN_DISTANCE && timeSinceLastUpdate < MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES)
    {
        var rejectMessage = $"Rejected point due to small movement and frequent updates: {distanceFromPrevious:F2}m in {timeSinceLastUpdate}ms";
        Console.WriteLine(rejectMessage);
        Logger.LogInfo(rejectMessage);
        return false;
    }

    if (speed > MAX_SPEED)
    {
        var rejectMessage = $"Rejected point due to high speed: {speed * 3.6:F2} km/h";
        Console.WriteLine(rejectMessage);
        Logger.LogInfo(rejectMessage);
        return false;
    }

    lastAcceptedLocation = newLocation;
    Console.WriteLine("Location valid");
    Logger.LogInfo("Location valid");
    return true;
}

